# Brightness bug in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, mobile, ios6

In my application at some parts I am changing brightness of the screen, and turning back to default value on some pages but if the user presses home button and exits from my application, when the brightness of the screen was changed I can't return the screen brightness back to its value.

I put code to return brightness to default on these delegate calls but it also didn't work

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

In some sites I read it is a bug of IOS, actually not bug but it doesn't give you permission to change the brightness: OS takes the control of it after home button is pressed.

But passbook app can do that so does anyone know is there a solution for this or passbook can do that because it is written by apple?

Answer (score -1):

If the issue is indeed that the brightness cannot be changed from the application delegate methods (and I'm not saying that that is the problem; I'm not sure), you could instead try changing it from `view[Will/Did]Disappear` on the relevant UIViewController.